# How to test that a discrete time series has markovian properties? How to use the Wilcoxon test to do so?

Tags: time-series, markov-process, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Let us assume I have a time series made of the following observations:

ts = c(163,18,53,189, 243, 101, 150, 39, 60,96,36,76,71,67,56,3,72,96,15,19)

How can I use the Wilcoxon test to determine if it respects Markov properties?

The actual data I am dealing with is made of about 500K observations. I have divided it into 5 chunks, then I have used the Wilcoxon--Mann--Whitney test to verify that the distribution of the whole series (500K obs) has the same distribution of its sub-series (the 5 chunks). Does it make sense?

The reason for asking this specific question is given by the test's popularity in the literature. See for example [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0370157311001530?casa_token=R-AAvxx53ecAAAAA:OJ95gQwUrXrCIxsQLm83kbmXuXo-3flhsoMMqCAQcslx82HDA_dlB-81pVADU1CblfYc4mQ).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe... I would take the first difference of the sequence and test whether the differences are (insert distribution) distributed. This would test whether two adjacent values are related, but not if two non-adjacent values are related.

Comment: It seems unnecessarily limiting to insist that one particular test be applied to your analysis.  Why not ask more generally how you could test the Markov property on a long time series?

Comment: @whuber you are right but the reason for asking this specific question is given by the test's popularity in the literature. See for example [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0370157311001530?casa_token=R-AAvxx53ecAAAAA:OJ95gQwUrXrCIxsQLm83kbmXuXo-3flhsoMMqCAQcslx82HDA_dlB-81pVADU1CblfYc4mQ).

Comment: Can you please add extra information, context and links/referenes to the post as an edit. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks. Done.